# How do I change an activities's boolean values or other variable values in another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, boolean, boolean-logic

So I have a boolean value in Activity A that is set to false. Then, in another activity I want to change that value to true. Then when i press the back button back to activity A, that boolean is now true and it runs that in the onCreate.

here's what I mean, Activity A

```
private static boolean newCardcheck = false;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 

}


public static void setNewCardcheck() {
    newCardcheck = true;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   if(newCardcheck)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"hey everyone",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        alfunction();
        sendCards(storeCards);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE)
    {
        newCardcheck = true;
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    MyActivity.setNewCardcheck();
    super.onBackPressed();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, getIntent());
    finish();
}
```

So when I press back, I want newCardcheck to be true and run the "if" statement not the else statement.

Hope you guys can help.

thanks.

And I also tried putting setNewCard() method in an onClick it didn't work either.

Comment: `onCreate(...)` may not run again when you navigate back to the first activity.  You should put that condition in `onResume()`.

Comment: @Kevin, which condition are you referring to?

Comment: `if(newCardcheck) ...`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is through SharedPreferences. SharedPreferences will write your data to a private file in a key/value within your app's apk that will persist even you turn your device off.

You can initialize SharedPreferences in onCreate like so: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE).

To store a value simply call:  sharedPreferences.edit().putString("myKey", stringValue).commit();

To retrieve that value anywhere from your application, initialize SharedPreferences, and then use the following code:  String myData = sharedPreferences.getString("myKey");

Let me know if that helps!

EDIT: You may also want to look into getting a result from your Intent. See [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Use SharedPreferences if you need the boolean to be persistent (ie: written to storage and available on reboot), otherwise you may want to try onActivityResult.

Edit 2:

Try overriding onActivityResult in Activity A as so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            myBoolean = true;
        }
}
```

Then in Activity B try

`setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, getIntent()); 
finish();`

This is the standard way of passing data to and from activities. Check out my link above about getting a result from an activity to delve a little deeper.

Comment: I thought the same thing. Use shared preferences.

Comment: I was thinking that. So initially i set newCardCheck = false; then I store that in preferences. My problem is in the other activity, if i call on that perference and change the value inside of it to true, and go back to activity A, will the if statement run?

Comment: Override `onResume` in Activity A and put your boolean logic in there. You can read more about the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) on Google's documentation.

Comment: Is onResume being called?

Comment: Observation 1) You forgot the `.show()` with that toast. Let me look at it a little bit more.

Comment: Remove  `MyActivity.setNewCardcheck();` in Activity B

Comment: I would also throw in a break point in onResume to ensure that it's being called.

Comment: @Zack, okay so it the onResume() works. I know onCreate() comes before onResume(), so if I set newCardCheck = true; (in onResume() )But if i do an if/else statement in the onCreate() that checks to see if newCardCheck is true, it will still read as false right?

Comment: @Zack, so i tested it, and put the toast back in the if/else in the onCreate(), and it still read it as true.

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if that helps at all. Without knowing the core logic of what you're trying to accomplish I can only help so much.

Comment: So basically what I'm doing is making like a Tinder swipe card app. In the activity A, I have a bunch of cards premade. in Activity B, you can make a card, and once you do its sent back to ACtivity A to be displayed. Now I first open the activity, you get the default cards, then you go to activity B to make a card, and press back it should pop up in activity A, and that's why I need that boolean to check.

Comment: I also applied the code above, but the toast never showed. I'm going to edit what i have.

Comment: @TheQ Your code in `onResume()` reads: if `newCardcheck` is true, set it to true.  I hope you can see that's nonsensical.  I meant you should move the `if`/`else` from `onCreate(...)` to `onResume()`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yeah that was a typo, i just put, super.onResume() and newCardcheck = true; but that still doesn't set it to true, in my onCreate, it still reads as false...

Comment: @TheQ Once again... REMOVE the conditional expression from `onCreate(...)` and put it in `onResume()`.  Not sure what's so hard about this.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede oh man, sorry I got it to work...I forgot to edit the code here. So yeah it was on the onresume. thanks Kevin.. sorry been working on 2hrs of sleep not thinking clearly. sorry about that guys.